# Нестандартная аккордеон-панель

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Здравствуйте. В проекте есть div со списком вкладок на подобии следующего примера

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,500);
.snip1231 {
  font-family: 'Raleway', Arial, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 500;
}
.snip1231 * {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.35s ease;
  transition: all 0.35s ease;
}
.snip1231 li {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: outside none none;
  margin: 0.5em 1em;
  padding: 0;
}
.snip1231 a {
  padding: 0.8em 17px;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  position: relative;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.snip1231 a:before,
.snip1231 a:after {
  left: 0%;
  right: 0%;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(0deg);
  transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(0deg);
  content: '';
  border-left: 12px solid #46627f;
  border-right: 12px solid #46627f;
  height: 3px;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.35s ease;
  transition: all 0.35s ease;
}
.snip1231 a:hover,
.snip1231 .current a {
  color: #ffffff;
}
.snip1231 a:hover:before,
.snip1231 .current a:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(12deg);
  transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(12deg);
}
.snip1231 a:hover:after,
.snip1231 .current a:after {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(-12deg);
  transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(-12deg);
}
/* Demo purposes only */
body {
  padding: 50px 0;
  background-color: #212121;
}
```

```html
<ul class="snip1231">
  <li class="current"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
<ul class="snip1231">
  <li class="current"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

Пример взят [от сюда](https://codepen.io/littlesnippets/pen/BogOYJ?depth=everything&order=popularity&page=4&q=horizontal%20menu&show_forks=false)

Необходимо сделать так, чтобы по клику на любой из представленных блоков из под него "выезжало" аккордеон-меню, как показано на рисунке ниже.

[image: Блок с аккордеон-меню]

Обратите внимание, что блок "выезжает" из блока, на которую нажал пользователь, и занимает собой всю ширину блока-контейнера.

Также в проекте уже есть bootstrap и jquery (+jquery-ui) так что если их использование здесь облегчит мне работу, пожалуйста, помогите найти им здесь применение.

Comment: кол-во табов в ширину всегда 3 ? если да, то проблемы не вижу. После каждой секции из 3х табов ставим блок - с нулевой высотой и по нажатию на табы у нас "раскрывается" нулевая высота.

Comment: Нет, не всегда 3) В этом и проблема) Чем шире экран, тем их больше. На телефоне их минимум две, на 768 - 3, на 1024 их 4, а на компьютере до 5-6 вроде доходит)